# OAuth scopes for different flows in same application?

Tags: node.js, github, oauth, passport.js

#### Context

I have a Node.js application that has a "complex" set of OAuth flows in order to make the UX simpler.

I have the usual login and registration flow where you may use an OAuth provider to authenticate. I don't require any special `scope` here, since OAuth is being used purely for authentication and the user has no reason to want to give me elevated access (say to private GitHub repositories), and might even think this is a shady thing to ask, so he goes away and never visits my product again. So, no `scope` for the pure authentication flow.

The application also has an import functionality where you can import a list of entities from an OAuth provider (say, GitHub repositories). By default, you aren't asked for any `scope` here either.

[image: example.png]

Clicking on the *"Looking for your private repositories?"* button authenticates you against GitHub again, asking for the `repo` scope. This is all fine and well.

#### The issue

Is that when the user tries to login again, or otherwise do anything that might authenticate them but doesn't explicitly request the `repo` scope, GitHub deems this an explicit downgrade request.

[image: downgrade.png]

The issue is **the user wouldn't want to downgrade** during logins for no particular reason. Similarly, **I don't want to ask for more permissions than I need during logins**.

Leaving things in this state would be even worse than asking for `repo` at login, but that would be an extremely poor choice as well.

#### Potential Solutions

Besides the two non-solutions, the potential solutions I've come up with are:

- Ask GitHub explicitly for **unique access tokens** based on the requested `scope`, store the tokens separately, and use them as needed afterwards

That'd be great, except it'd be way too stateful and I haven't found a way to do it anyways; they seem to give you a single token per application user, and I suspect this is how OAuth works, for the most part, but I'm hardly an expert on the matter.

- Tell GitHub explicitly **not to downgrade** a token if it has more priviledge than what it's asking for.

This sounds to me that it should be the default behavior. Anyways, **is there any way I can tell GitHub not to downgrade a token?**

If not, is there any other way I can fix this without resorting to asking for the same scope across the entire application? This would partially defeat the purpose of scopes in the first place.

Also, is this a GitHub-specific issue? Will I have to deal with this in a provider-by-provider basis? Is there a protocol-level solution that miraculously makes the problem go away? Or is OAuth just not built with UX in mind?

FWIW I'm using `iojs` and `passportjs`, but I don't think that has anything to do with the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the issue was in my code, as it usually goes. I was explicitly setting a property *(`options.scope: []`, for those using passport)* on the authentication flow, and that resulted in a GitHub authorization URL that contained `&scope=&`, meaning I was explicitly asking for a downgrade.

Removing the option in case I have no explicit scope to ask for fixed the issue. Woo!